# Planar sections of convex sets in Cartan-Hadamard manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $X$ be a convex set in Euclidean space $\mathbf{R}^n$ and $p\in\mathbf{R}^n$ be a fixed point. Then any plane $\Pi$ passing through $p$ intersects $X$ in a convex set. Conversely,  this property quickly identifies convex subsets of $\mathbf{R}^n$. Indeed, given $x$, $x'\in X$, let $\Pi$ be a plane passing through $p$, $x$, $x'$. Then the line segment $xx'\subset\Pi\cap X\subset X$.

Can convex subsets be identified similarly in a Cartan-Hadamard manifold $M$, i.e., a complete simply connected Riemannian space with nonpositive curvature? A subset of $M$ is convex if it contains the geodesic segment connecting every pair of its points, and we can define the planes $\Pi$ as the image under the exponential map of two dimensional subspaces of $T_p M$. Then $\Pi$ itself is a Cartan-Hadamard space, and we assume that $\Pi\cap X$ is a convex subset of $\Pi$.

In the case where $M$ is the hyperbolic space $\mathbf{H}^n$, the proof in $\mathbf{R}^n$ works just as well, because planes in $\mathbf{H}^n$ are totally geodesic. In a generic manifold, however, there exists no totally geodesic submanifold of dimension bigger than one.

Comment: Are you asking whether one can characterize convex subsets of Cartan-Hadamard manifold in terms of their two-dimensional "sections"? What is meant by a "section" in your question? As you say, in a general Cartan-Hadamard manifold there will be no 2-dimensional convex set whose relative interior contains a given point, so we cannot define a "section" as a 2-dimensional convex set.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: Thanks, I edited the question to clarify this point.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the proposed characterization.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: The question is whether $X$ is convex assuming that $\Pi\cap X$ is a convex subset of $\Pi$, for all planes $\Pi$ passing through some point $p$ of $M$. A subset of $\Pi$ (which itself is a Cartan-Hadamard space) is convex if every pair of points of $\Pi$ can be joined by a geodesic of $\Pi$ which lie in that set.

Comment: So you are not asking for a characterization. It is one way: if each $\Pi\cap X$ is convex, then $X$ is convex.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: Yes, I changed the word "characterized" to "identified".

Comment: What metric do you put on $\Pi$? These submanifolds are hardly ever totally geodesic and, thus, will intersect geodesic segments in $X$ in disconnected subsets. I do not see how they can be possibly used to detect convexity in $X$ unless $X$ has constant curvature.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: The induced metric.